# Ruby Puma see all threads if they are occupied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I want to see if something is slow and occupied doing a request. Or if it is time to scale up.

I used `Puma.stats`  but it only returns:

```
{
"started_at": "2020-09-07T14:43:53Z",
"backlog": 0,
"running": 7,
"pool_capacity": 3,
"max_threads": 7
}
```

I cannot see if the threadpool is full. Is there a way of seeing that info?

Answer (score 2):

`Puma.stats` includes the information needed to know how many Puma threads are occupied. According to Puma's documentation, [pool_capacity](https://puma.io/puma/Puma/Server.html#pool_capacity-instance_method) is the number of threads that are not occupied:

> This number represents the number of requests that the server is capable of taking right now.
>
> For example if the number is 5 then it means there are 5 threads sitting idle ready to take a request. If one request comes in, then the value would be 4 until it finishes processing.